# Struts Action called twice

Tags: java, struts

I have something like in a jsp page:

```
 <a id="action_url_1" href="/war/action/click=true" name="action_url_1">Click Here</a>
```

The `execute()` method is being called twice.

Can someone please help.

Comment: I have not been able to reproduce the issue with Firefox. This issue is with IE.

Comment: There's no way to help with the information provided.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the whole page if there is a href for # in that case action method called twice and if you are using tiles then  all the tiles page for the same hope this will solve your problem.
and for further reference click the following link
http://qa.compilr.org/28/why-action-called-twice-in-struts2